# pandas python Update subset of column A based on subset of one or more other columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Edit** I've revised portions of the description below to clarify what I mean by "feature" and "group", fix a typo, and include additional code I've tried.

My pandas `df` has 4.5 mil rows and 23 columns. The table below shows a few lines from `df2` which is generated from `df`. It shows two groups (*eeskin* and *hduquant*) and three features (*failed*, *exit_status*, and *job_number*):

```
# report by group

        group      feature  #_cats #_jobs  rank        top_value  freq  \
10   eeskin    failed       1       6     -1     100              6      
21   eeskin    exit_status  1       6     -1     0                6     
0    eeskin    job_number   1       6     -1     4.08219e+06      6      
21   hduquant  exit_status  5       64    -1     37               58     
11   hduquant  failed       2       64    -1     0                63     
1    hduquant  job_number   2       64    -1     4.07192e+06      61
```

The "rank" column value of -1 is a placeholder.

I want to update each group's rank for each feature. "Feature" in this case means each unique value in the "feature" column: *failed*, *exit_status*, and *job_number*. Updating the rankings for *job_number*, for example, means modifying the values in column "rank" only on rows where column "feature" equals *job_number*. As it turns out each of these rows also corresponds to a different group value in the "group" column.

So rather than update all values in column "rank" at once, I want to do them feature by feature where each write updates the values for all groups on a single feature.

The rank for feature "job_number" is based on the value of "#_jobs" col (highest number of jobs is rank 1). For feature "failed", rank is based on the "freq" of "top_value". `exits_status` can remain -1 for now.

The result should look like this:

```
        group      feature  #_cats #_jobs  rank        top_value  freq  \
10   eeskin    failed       1       6      1     100              6      
21   eeskin    exit_status  1       6     -1     0                6     
0    eeskin    job_number   1       6      2     4.08219e+06      6      
21   hduquant  exit_status  5       64    -1     37               58     
11   hduquant  failed       2       64     2     0                63     
1    hduquant  job_number   2       64     1     4.07192e+06      61
```

"eeskin" ranks 1 for `failed` and 2 for `job_number`. "hdquant" ranks 2 for `failed` and 1 for `job_number`.

I am able to update the rank values for `job_number` with this code:

```
if feat == 'job_number':
     grouped = grouped.sort_values("#_jobs", ascending=False)
     grouped['rank'] = grouped.index + 1
```

```
        group      feature  #_cats #_jobs  rank        top_value  freq  \
10   eeskin    failed       1       6     -1     100              6      
21   eeskin    exit_status  1       6     -1     0                6     
0    eeskin    job_number   1       6      2     4.08219e+06      6      
21   hduquant  exit_status  5       64    -1     37               58     
11   hduquant  failed       2       64    -1     0                63     
1    hduquant  job_number   2       64     1     4.07192e+06      61
```

But when I try to update both, neither is updated:

```
feat = ['job_number', 'failed']

for f in feat:
    if f == 'job_number':
        grouped = grouped.sort_values("#_jobs", ascending=False)
        grouped['rank'] = grouped.index + 1
    elif f == 'failed':  #  or f == 'exit_status'
        x = len(not grouped[f] == 0)
        grouped['x'] = x
        grouped = grouped.sort_values("x", ascending=False)
        grouped['rank'] = grouped.index + 1      
        del grouped['x']
```

```
        group      feature  #_cats #_jobs  rank        top_value  freq  \
10   eeskin    failed       1       6     -1     100              6      
21   eeskin    exit_status  1       6     -1     0                6     
0    eeskin    job_number   1       6     -1     4.08219e+06      6      
21   hduquant  exit_status  5       64    -1     37               58     
11   hduquant  failed       2       64    -1     0                63     
1    hduquant  job_number   2       64    -1     4.07192e+06      61
```

I've tried to implement the suggestion from Matt W. but so far without success:

```
df.loc[df.feature == 'job', 'rank'] = df.loc[df.feature == 'job', 'jobs'].rank(ascending=False)
```

I modified his code a bit as follows but also without success:

```
df2.loc[df2['feature' == 'job_number'] & df2['rank']] = (df2.loc[df2['#_jobs']].rank(ascending=False))
```

---

**Addendum** @Matt W.

Input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['g1', 'u1', 3902779, '2018-09-27 21:38:06', '2018-10-01 07:24:38', '2018-10-01 08:00:42', 0, 0, 'single', 1, 55696, 609865728.0, 4.0, 6.0, 0, 0, 4.0, 0, 'single', 1, 0, pd.Timedelta('3 days 09:46:32'), pd.Timedelta('00:36:04')]], 
                          columns=['group', 'owner', 'job_number', 'submission_time', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'failed', 'exit_status', 'granted_pe', 'slots', 'task_number', 'maxvmem', 'h_data', 'h_rt', 'highp', 'exclusive', 'h_vmem', 'gpu', 'pe', 'slot', 'campus', 'wait_time', 'wtime'])
df = (df.astype(dtype={'group':'str', 'owner':'str', 'job_number':'int', 'submission_time':'datetime64[ns]', 'start_time':'datetime64[ns]', 'end_time':'datetime64[ns]', 'failed':'int', 'exit_status':'int', 'granted_pe':'str', 'slots':'int', 'task_number':'int', 'maxvmem':'float', 'h_data':'float', 'h_rt':'float', 'highp':'int', 'exclusive':'int', 'h_vmem':'float', 'gpu':'int', 'pe':'str', 'slot':'int', 'campus':'int', 'wait_time':'timedelta64[ns]', 'wtime':'timedelta64[ns]'}))
df
```

Output:

```
         group  owner  job_number      submission_time           start_time             end_time  failed  exit_status  granted_pe  slots  task_number       maxvmem  h_data  h_rt  highp  exclusive  h_vmem  gpu      pe  slot  campus       wait_time     wtime
      0  g1     u1     3902779     2018-09-27 21:38:06  2018-10-01 07:24:38  2018-10-01 08:00:42  0       0            single      1      55696         609865728.0  4.0     6.0   0      0          4.0     0    single  1     0      3 days 09:46:32  00:36:04  
4080243  g50    u92    4071923     2018-10-25 02:08:14  2018-10-27 01:41:58  2018-10-27 02:08:50  0       0            shared      1      119          7.654482e+08  2.5     1.5   0      1          16.0    0    shared  1     0      1 days 23:33:44  00:26:52
4080244  g50    u92    4071922     2018-10-25 02:08:11  2018-10-27 01:46:53  2018-10-27 02:08:53  0       0            shared      1      2208         1.074463e+09  2.5     1.5   0      10         24.0    0    shared  1     0      1 days 23:38:42  00:22:00
```

The code produces the first line. I tacked on a couple more lines just for variety.

There are 203 groups, 699 owners. There are thousands of jobs: a "job" is defined as a unique combination of job_number, task_number, and submission_time.

I want to create an overall report and one report per group, both focused on resource usage.

**Components of overall report**:

General stats:

- count, mean, std, min, 25%, 50%, 75%, max (numerical)
- count, unique, top, freq (string)
- count, first, last  # time delta cols (time delta)

Jobs:

- job_number with the most task_numbers, job_number w most submission times
- job (as defined above) with earliest/latest

  - submission_time, start_time, and end_time
- job with most

  - failed != 0
  - exit_status != 0
- job with most (sum of values)

  - granted_pe, slots, maxvmem, h_data, h_rt, exclusive, h_vmem, and gpu
- job with most (count/len)

  - pe == single
  - pe == shared
  - pe == for each addtl category of pe
- job with longest/shortest cumulative

  - wait_time and wtime

Owners:

- owner with the most jobs
- owner with earliest/latest

  - submission_time, start_time, end_time
- owner with most

  - failed != 0
  - exit_status != 0
- owner with most (sum of values)

  - granted_pe, slots, maxvmem, h_data, h_rt, exclusive, h_vmem, gpu
- owner with most (count/len)

  - pe == single
  - pe == shared
  - pe == for each addtl category of pe
- owner with longest/shortest cumulative

  - wait_time and wtime

Groups:

- group with the most jobs
- group with the most owners
- group with earliest/latest

  - submission_time, start_time, and end_time
- group with most

  - failed != 0
  - exit_status != 0
- group with most (sum of values) of each

  - granted_pe, slots, maxvmem, h_data, h_rt, exclusive, h_vmem, and gpu
- group with most

  - pe == single
  - pe == shared
  - pe == for each addtl category of pe
- group with longest/shortest cumulative

  - wait_time and wtime

**Components of individual "by group" reports**:

By feature (column in df):

General stats:

- count, mean, std, min, 25%, 50%, 75%, max (numerical)
- count, unique, top, freq (string)
- count, first, last  # time delta cols (time delta)

The group's stats:

By job:

- job_number with the most task_numbers, job_number w most submission_times
- job (as defined above) with earliest/latest

  - submission_time, start_time, and end_time
- job with most

  - failed != 0
  - exit_status != 0
- job with most

  - granted_pe, slots, maxvmem, h_data, h_rt, exclusive, h_vmem, and gpu
- job with most

  - pe == single (count/len)
  - pe == shared (count/len)
  - pe == for each addtl category of pe (count/len)
- job with longest/shortest cumulative

  - wait_time and wtime

By owner:

- owner with the most jobs
- owner with earliest/latest

  - submission_time, start_time, end_time
- owner with most

  - failed != 0
  - exit_status != 0
- owner with most

  - granted_pe, slots, maxvmem, h_data, h_rt, exclusive, h_vmem, and gpu
- owner with most

  - pe == single (count/len)
  - pe == shared (count/len)
  - pe == for each addtl category of pe (count/len)
- owner with longest/shortest cumulative

  - wait_time and wtime

By ranking:

Here I want each group ranked against all other groups, from 1 with highest usage or most "fails" to 203 for lowest usage. I will use these values to plot a graph for each group.

Rank for:

- number of

  - jobs, job_numbers, task_numbers, submission times
- time of first

  - submission_time, start_time, end_time
- time of last

  - submission_time, start_time, end_time
- number of

  - failed != 0
  - exit_status != 0
- number of

  - granted_pe, slots, maxvmem, h_data, h_rt, exclusive, h_vmem, and gpu
- number of

  - pe == single
  - pe == shared
  - pe == for each addtl category of pe
- total cumulative for all jobs

  - wait_time and wtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this an easier way by using pandas `.loc`

Initialize dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['e','e','e','h','h','h'],
                   'feature':['fail', 'exit', 'job', 'exit', 'fail', 'job'],
                   'cats':[1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2],
                   'jobs':[1, 1, 1, 64, 64, 64],
                   'rank':[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   'topvalue':[100, 0, 4, 37, 0, 3.9],
                   'freq':[1, 1, 1, 58, 63, 61]
})
```

We want to rank jobs feature so we just isolate the rank locations using `.loc`, and then on the right side of the assignment, we isolate the jobs column using `.loc` and use the `.rank()` function

Rank job feature, by jobs value:

```
df.loc[df.feature == 'job', 'rank'] = df.loc[df.feature == 'job', 'jobs'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Rank failure feature by frequency where top value is not 0:

For this one you do rank the ones that are 0 which seems to go against what you said. So we'll do this two ways.

This way we *filter out the 0s* to start, and rank everything else. This will have the `top_value == 0` ranks stay as -1

```
df.loc[(df.feature == 'fail') & (df.topvalue != 0), 'rank'] = (
        df.loc[(df.feature == 'fail') & (df.topvalue != 0), 'freq']).rank(ascending=True)
```

This way we don't filter out the 0s.

```
df.loc[(df.feature == 'fail') & (df.topvalue != 0), 'rank'] = (
        df.loc[(df.feature == 'fail') & (df.topvalue != 0), 'freq']).rank(ascending=True)
```

Comment: This looks promising but when I tested it I realized my df is actually a GroupBy object. Error message suggests using `.apply()` method. How would I go about that?

Comment: `for feat2 in features2:` `grouped = df.groupby('group')[feat2]`
    
`grouped.loc[grouped.feature == 'job', 'rank'] = grouped.loc[grouped.feature == 'job', 'jobs'].rank(ascending=False)` --> "AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Comment: Dont' do the for feat in features part. don't groupby the dataframe. Leave it as is.

Comment: If you have a ton of features like 20+, that you need to do this with, and they each use a different column for rank, I would then suggest creating 1 column with the ranking values, and grouping by and ranking based on that 1 column.

Comment: But doing it the `loc` way is probably best just don't groupby the dataframe.

Comment: In trying to make the data small and simple for my question, I've made it more difficult for me to figure out how to implement your solution. My main df has shape (4500000, 23). I want to calculate "rank" for most cols. Prior to the groupby "group" data in my OP, I grouped the data by "feature" to add "by feature" stats to each feature GroupBy object. I'm in the weeds now. I agree `.loc` is better than my way, It's just not clear to me how to implement your solution on my original df since it does not contain all the stats columns. I'll try converting the SeriesGroupBy objects to DataFrames.

Comment: So is 1 stats column related to 1 feature spec? And if so, is the only condition for ranking ascending or descending?

Comment: thanks for your help. I feel the solution is pretty straightforward as you've suggested, I just haven't gotten it to work. I've posted an addendum to my original post: code to generate a few lines of my original `df` --- not the summary table I first posted --- and the simple stats and rankings I'm seeking. Not quite 1 stat 1 feature, some features have multiple stats, some have none. As detailed, I need to break them out in a combo of overall and by- feature, job, owner and group.

Comment: I found an answer that works for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55072621/9677043). It uses groupby and loc/iloc.