# pandas Add new "rank" columns for every column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like so (actual df has 4.5 mil rows, 23 cols):

```
group  feature  col1  col2  col3
g1     f1       1     10    100
g1     f1       11    9     1000
g1     f2       0     8     200
g2     f1       2     7     330
g2     f2       3     7     331
g2     f3       1     7     100
g3     f1       1     6     101
g3     f1       5     9     100
g3     f1       1     8     100
```

I want to add two new "rank" cols for each col in my df. I will evaluate different cols differently, such as sum, mean, max, etc. For ease of explanation I've broken the problem out into two separate problems below.

I have been advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55034835/9677043) to use `.loc` and not use `groupby`, but any solution that works is fine. I've tried both and had little success (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55034626/9677043))

The first rank col will rank each feature on the values in col1, col2, and col3 *within each group*.

At an intermediate stage it would look something like this:

```
group  feature  col1  col1_sum  col1_rank  col2  col2_avg  col2_rank  col3 col3_max  col3_rank
g1     f1       1     12        1          10    9.5       1          100  1000      1
g1     f1       11                         9                          1000           
g1     f2       0     0         2          8     8         2          200  200       2
g2     f1       2     2         2          7     7         1          330  330       2
g2     f2       3     3         1          7     7         1          331  331       1
g2     f3       1     1         3          7     7         1          100  100       3
g3     f1       1     7         1          6     7.67      1          101  101       1
g3     f1       5                          9                          100            
g3     f1       1                          8                          100
```

It will output this:

```
group  feature  col1_rank  col2_rank  col3_rank
g1     f1       1          1          1
g1     f2       2          2          2
g2     f1       2          1          2
g2     f2       1          1          1
g2     f3       3          1          3
g3     f1       1          1          1
```

The second rank col will rank each group by feature on the values in col1, col2, and col3 *against all other groups*.

At an intermediate stage it would look something like this:

```
group  feature  col1  col1_sum  col1_rank  col2  col2_avg  col2_rank  col3 col3_max  col3_rank
g1     f1       1     12        1          10    9.5       1          100  1000      1
g1     f1       11                         9                          1000           
g2     f1       2     2         3          7     7         3          330  330       2
g3     f1       1     7         2          6     7.67      2          101  101       3
g3     f1       5                          9                          100            
g3     f1       1                          8                          100            

g1     f2       0     0         2          8     8         1          200  200       2
g2     f2       3     3         1          7     7         2          331  331       1

g2     f3       1     1         1          7     7         1          100  100       1
```

It will output this:

```
group  feature  col1_rank  col2_rank  col3_rank
g1     f1       1          1          1
g2     f1       3          3          2
g3     f1       2          2          3
g1     f2       2          1          2
g2     f2       1          2          1
g2     f3       1          1          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `groupby` on `['group', 'feature']` to produce an intermediary dataframe containing the sum, avg and max columns (not the ranks), and then again `groupby` on `group` only to produce the ranks.

Intermediary dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.concat([
    df.iloc[:,[0,1,2]].groupby(['group', 'feature']).sum(),
    df.iloc[:,[0,1,3]].groupby(['group', 'feature']).mean(),
    df.iloc[:,[0,1,4]].groupby(['group', 'feature']).max()
    ], axis=1)
```

The intermediary dataframe is:

```
               col1      col2  col3
group feature                      
g1    f1         12  9.500000  1000
      f2          0  8.000000   200
g2    f1          2  7.000000   330
      f2          3  7.000000   331
      f3          1  7.000000   100
g3    f1          7  7.666667   101
```

Now for the final dataframe:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('group').rank(method='min', ascending=False).reset_index()
```

which finally gives:

```
  group feature  col1  col2  col3
0    g1      f1   1.0   1.0   1.0
1    g1      f2   2.0   2.0   2.0
2    g2      f1   2.0   1.0   2.0
3    g2      f2   1.0   1.0   1.0
4    g2      f3   3.0   1.0   3.0
5    g3      f1   1.0   1.0   1.0
```

---

For the second part of the question, I would just change the indexing of the intermediary dataframe, and compute ranks after grouping on `'feature'`:

```
dfx4 = dfx.reset_index().set_index(['feature', 'group']
                                   ).sort_index().groupby('feature').rank(
                                   method='min', ascending=False
                                   ).reset_index()
```

which gives:

```
  feature group  col1  col2  col3
0      f1    g1   1.0   1.0   1.0
1      f1    g2   3.0   3.0   2.0
2      f1    g3   2.0   2.0   3.0
3      f2    g1   2.0   1.0   2.0
4      f2    g2   1.0   2.0   1.0
5      f3    g2   1.0   1.0   1.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly for the first case. I learned a lot from your example. For the second case, I tried grouping on just 'feature' but it gives the wrong result, this 3-row intermediary table that splits "f" and digit under 'group' and 'feature': `group feature  col1_sum  col2_avg  col3_max` `0     f       1        21  8.166667      1000` `1     f       2         3  7.500000       331` `2     f       3         1  7.000000       100` Note the intermediary is different here: features are grouped together (f1's for all groups, etc.). The sum/avg/max results are different from case 1.